# Detecting the position in page. If end of page then write at the bottom, else write in situ

Tags: page-breaking, page, layout

I need to detect the position of the "cursor" in the page. I need a command which writes either "in situ" or at the bottom of the page (via `\vfill` directive) depending on whether it is the last thing in that page.

The MWE is :

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\midorlast}[1]{%
    % do \vfill if nothing is left in the page to write.
    \vfill
    \framebox[\textwidth]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Wishes be horses.
%\midorlast{Mid Page} % ideally this should be just below the last paragraph without any space produced.

Horses be wishes.
\midorlast{End of page} % this shoould go at the bottom of the page


\end{document}
```

Any idea ... how do I achieve that?

Comment: You can use `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal`.

Comment: This can be done (quite easily) without checking location on one run, and using that to choose on the next run. Do you want to choose based on  "it is tha last thing in that page" or "nothing left (in the page) to write"? They are quite different!

Comment: @DonaldArseneau I would like to differentiate between "_mid page_ material", "it is the last thing in that _particular page_ to write" OR "nothing _left_ in the _document_ to write". is it possible?

Comment: My first impression of it being easy is complicated by having `\end{document}` enter the picture, or any `\newpage` (like with `\chapter`). Even in the simple case of a natural (unforced) page break, my easy idea fails when you have both "mid page" and "last page" on the same page. Sorry.

Comment: Please write your idea as a comment at least. I have some compromise solutions which compromises too much... I would very much like to see other ideas